# ui-router Dependency included still getting the error[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am actually trying to use $stateProvider routing but it gives the error; Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module moduleTry due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider

The angular-ui-router.js is included after the angular.js file in my index page. I have included the ui-router dependency in my app.js file also. 
I could not get the answer even after a lot of research. Please help

Index.htmI

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>


  <script src="app/vendors/angular-1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app/vendors/angular-1.4.8/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app/vendors/angular-locale_en-in.js"></script>
  <script src="app/assets/css/styles.css"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/try.app.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/try.config.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/try.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="app/scripts/try.router.js"></script> 


</head>

<body ng-app="moduleTry">
  <h2>AngularJS Ui router - Demonstration</h2>

  <div class="container">
      <a href="#home"></a>Home</li>
      <a href="#about-us"></a>About</li>
  </div>

      <div ui-view>

      </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

try.app.js

```
(function(){

    angular.module('moduleTry',[
    'ui.router'
    ])

})();
```

try.config.js

```
(function(){
    "use-strict"


})();
```

try.controller.js

(function(){
    "use-strict";

```
angular.module("moduleTry",)

.controller('tryController',['$scope',function($scope){
     $scope.name ="Karan";
    }]);
})();
```

try.route.js

```
"use-strict";

        angular.module('moduleTry')
             .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

            $stateProvider
                .state("home",{
                    url: "/home",
                    templateUrl: "Template/template1.html"
                })
                .state("about-us", {
                    url: "/about-us",
                    templateUrl: "Template/template2.html"
                })
             }]);
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca8rn.png)

Comment: Try injecting $state into the try.route.js config then, see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: i tried to include the $state to try.route.js but  the issue remained the same.

Answer (score 0):

That error would appear, if you would firstly do correct setter init

```
(function(){

    angular.module('moduleTry',[
    'ui.router'
    ])

})();
```

And then.. accidentally - redefine it

```
angular.module('moduleTry',[])
```

And if you check your controller code, there is a type very close to it

```
angular.module("moduleTry",)
```

that is wrong, it must be

```
angular.module("moduleTry")
```

Comment: i made the changes and used angular.module("moduleTry") in all the js files ie in try.app.js, try.controller.js,  try.route.js  but the issue remains the same.

Comment: you can create a plunker.. and show how it is broken. There is one mine.. which is working. Adjust it to reproduce the problem, I am ready to assist then http://plnkr.co/edit/4pjoofCXq444kjXLqGx8?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have created the plunker.. i have included the files in index.html as they are in my project. Please let me know if any changes are required      https://plnkr.co/edit/PZefP3aF2kmxL7tGaIVZ?p=preview.

Comment: i have made some changes to the code so please just refer to the plunker. and please notify me the errors.

Comment: I fixed your plunker and made it working. The biggest issue was *(as I expected)* the controller files .. and re-declaration `angular.module("about.moduleTry", [])` of the module.. check working stuff here https://plnkr.co/edit/UMOqwg5jQqqxfOj7Mdr4?p=preview

Comment: I have tried to make the changes but the error is not resolving . I do see that you have made some changes in the filename but I have a different paths and i have specified them correctly . Moreover i did not get you on redeclaration part. Please Explain